# Insert report viewer into the a html page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

I need to insert the reportviewer between the div elements

The online documentation tells me that I have to drag and drop onto the form page. I did'nt see anything about inserting into a html doc. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular HTML pages does not support ASP.NET controls such as the ReportViewer. You need to create an ASPX page to host a ReportViewer.

Comment: Thomas Li: Thanks. Do you know if it will on mvc3, and cshtml pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx for using the `ReportViewer` control in a MVC project.

Comment: I found to blog in the above answer to not be a suitable solution for .net 4 and mvc 3.

Answer (score 0):

ReportViewer is a server control and can't be added into a razor view. You can added a ReportViewer into any ASPX view page or view user control.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513) for more details.