# How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reportviewer

I'm trying to use a reportviewer control, within a razor view, in the mvc 3 framework. The [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104.aspx) talks of drag and drop. Any suggestion on how to insert it into the view.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**The following solution works only for single page reports. Refer to comments for more details.**

ReportViewer is a server control and thus can not be used within a razor view. However you can add a ASPX view page, view user control or traditional web form that containing a ReportViewer into the application.

You will need to ensure that you have added the [relevant handler into your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx).

If you use a ASPX view page or view user control you will need to set 
AsyncRendering to false to get the report to display properly.

*Update:*

Added more sample code. Note there are no meaningful changes required in Global.asax.

**Web.Config**

Mine ended up as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Controller**

The controller actions are very simple.

As a bonus the File() action returns the output of "TestReport.rdlc" as a PDF file.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

...

public class PDFController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public FileResult File()
    {
        ReportViewer rv = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
        rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/TestReport.rdlc");
        rv.LocalReport.Refresh();

        byte[] streamBytes = null;
        string mimeType = "";
        string encoding = "";
        string filenameExtension = "";
        string[] streamids = null;
        Warning[] warnings = null;

        streamBytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

        return File(streamBytes, mimeType, "TestReport.pdf");
    }

    public ActionResult ASPXView()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ASPXUserControl()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**ASPXView.apsx**

The ASPXView is as follows.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>ASPXView</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <script runat="server">
            private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/TestReport.rdlc");
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
        </script>
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">          
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:reportviewer id="ReportViewer1" runat="server" height="500" width="500" AsyncRendering="false"></rsweb:reportviewer>
        </form>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ViewUserControl1.ascx**

The ASPX user control looks like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<script runat="server">
  private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/TestReport.rdlc");
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
  }
</script>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```

**ASPXUserControl.cshtml**

Razor view. Requires ViewUserControl1.ascx.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ASPXUserControl";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>ASPXUserControl</h2>
@Html.Partial("ViewUserControl1")
```

**References**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx

[bind report to reportviewer in web mvc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296485/bind-report-to-reportviewer-in-web-mvc2)

Comment: I would love to see a more complete example. Are you creating the ASPX page in a completely new project? Or is it co-existing with the MVC3 web application? I am unable to show the aspx page as the routing cant seem to find it in my MVC3 project (I tried using the full path in the file system). And I guess the web.config needs a lot of work to get the report viewer component working also?

Comment: I fortunately still have my test application when I was try to resolve the issue for myself and have update my answer with all the meaningful changes. The ASPX page is within the same MVC3 web application. My test application didn't use any special routing, you must have a unrelated issue.

Comment: Did you tested it with ServerReports. Because it renders for me the initial Report page but when i click on any button in the control (e.g. "Next Page") it does nothing.

Comment: No, tested only with local reports.

Comment: I have the same problem with ServerReports, the first page renders fine but any callbacks produce nothing.

Comment: I had the same problem as @rudimenter and solved it by making a true WebForm with code behind, and sticking it in an iframe on a Razor view.

I now have a fully functional ReportViewer

Comment: @AdrianToman please update the answer to indicate that it only works on the first page, in order not to that future readers should not have to waist their time on that

Comment: This only works for single page reports (even for local reports) as the post-back mechanism doesn't work in MVC, for a complete solution as well as to enable the use of AsyncRendering="true" see my answer below.

Comment: @rudimenter Did someone solve the postback problem with a ServerReport? Is the best solution to use a iframe?

Comment: @ministrymason yes i iframed it. Looks like thats the only way to make it work.

Comment: And what namespace/reference is needed for the `ReportViewer` vcariable in the PDFController? It doesn't compile just like that, and how can you publish code that simply doesn't work as an answer?

Comment: @ProfK I have added the required using statements to the `PDFController` code sample.

Comment: See my answer below for ServerReports.

Comment: It seem to be working but I kept hiting 401 unauthorized. I created a DataSourceCredentials objet with Name and password attributes set to the ones I used in the browser, then a List of DatasourceCredentials and send it to serverReport.SetDataSourceCredentials. But still 401. any hints?

Answer (score 13):

This is a simple task. You can follow the following steps.

1. Create a folder in your solution and name it ***Reports***.
2. Add an ASP.Net web form and name it ***ReportView.aspx***
3. Create a Class ***ReportData*** and add it to the ***Reports*** folder. Add the  following code to the Class.

   ```
   public class ReportData  
   {  
       public ReportData()  
       {  
           this.ReportParameters = new List<Parameter>();  
           this.DataParameters = new List<Parameter>();  
       }

       public bool IsLocal { get; set; }
       public string ReportName { get; set; }
       public List<Parameter> ReportParameters { get; set; }
       public List<Parameter> DataParameters { get; set; }
   }

   public class Parameter  
   {  
       public string ParameterName { get; set; }  
       public string Value { get; set; }  
   }
   ```
4. Add another Class and name it ***ReportBasePage.cs***. Add the following code in this Class.

   ```
   public class ReportBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected ReportData ReportDataObj { get; set; }

       protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnInit(e);
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
               if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportData"] != null)
               {
                   ReportDataObj = HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportData"] as ReportData;
                   return;
               }
           ReportDataObj = new ReportData();
           CaptureRouteData(Page.Request);
       }


       private void CaptureRouteData(HttpRequest request)
       {
           var mode = (request.QueryString["rptmode"] + "").Trim();
           ReportDataObj.IsLocal = mode == "local" ? true : false;
           ReportDataObj.ReportName = request.QueryString["reportname"] + "";
           string dquerystr = request.QueryString["parameters"] + "";
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dquerystr.Trim()))
           {
               var param1 = dquerystr.Split(',');
               foreach (string pm in param1)
               {
                   var rp = new Parameter();
                   var kd = pm.Split('=');
                   if (kd[0].Substring(0, 2) == "rp")
                   {
                       rp.ParameterName = kd[0].Replace("rp", "");
                       if (kd.Length > 1) rp.Value = kd[1];
                       ReportDataObj.ReportParameters.Add(rp);
                   }
                   else if (kd[0].Substring(0, 2) == "dp")
                   {
                       rp.ParameterName = kd[0].Replace("dp", "");
                       if (kd.Length > 1) rp.Value = kd[1];
                       ReportDataObj.DataParameters.Add(rp);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add ***ScriptManager*** to the ***ReportView.aspx*** page. Now add a *Report Viewer* to the page. In report viewer set the property ***AsyncRendering="false"***. The code is given below.

   ```
       <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerRSFReports" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false"
           Width="1271px" Height="1000px" >
       </rsweb:ReportViewer>
   ```
6. Add two ***NameSpace*** in ***ReportView.aspx.cs***

   ```
   using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
   using System.IO;
   ```
7. Change the ***System.Web.UI.Page*** to ***ReportBasePage***. Just replace your code using the following.

   ```
   public partial class ReportView : ReportBasePage
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (!IsPostBack)
           {
               RenderReportModels(this.ReportDataObj);
           }
       }

       private void RenderReportModels(ReportData reportData)
       {
           // This is the Data Access Layer from which a method is called to fill data to the list.
           RASolarERPData dal = new RASolarERPData();
           List<ClosingInventoryValuation> objClosingInventory = new List<ClosingInventoryValuation>();

           // Reset report properties.
           ReportViewerRSFReports.Height = Unit.Parse("100%");
           ReportViewerRSFReports.Width = Unit.Parse("100%");
           ReportViewerRSFReports.CssClass = "table";

           // Clear out any previous datasources.
           this.ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

           // Set report mode for local processing.
           ReportViewerRSFReports.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

           // Validate report source.
           var rptPath = Server.MapPath(@"./Report/" + reportData.ReportName +".rdlc");

           //@"E:\RSFERP_SourceCode\RASolarERP\RASolarERP\Reports\Report\" + reportData.ReportName + ".rdlc";
           //Server.MapPath(@"./Report/ClosingInventory.rdlc");

           if (!File.Exists(rptPath))
               return;

           // Set report path.
           this.ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.ReportPath = rptPath;

           // Set report parameters.
           var rpPms = ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.GetParameters();
           foreach (var rpm in rpPms)
           {
               var p = reportData.ReportParameters.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ParameterName.ToLower() == rpm.Name.ToLower());
               if (p != null)
               {
                   ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter(rpm.Name, p.Value);
                   ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp);
               }
           }

           //Set data paramater for report SP execution
           objClosingInventory = dal.ClosingInventoryReport(this.ReportDataObj.DataParameters[0].Value);

           // Load the dataSource.
           var dsmems = ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames();
           ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsmems[0], objClosingInventory));

           // Refresh the ReportViewer.
           ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.Refresh();
       }
   }
   ```
8. Add a Folder to the ***Reports*** Folder and name it ***Report***. Now add a ***RDLC*** report to the ***Reports/Report*** folder and name it ***ClosingInventory.rdlc***.
9. Now add a Controller and name it ***ReportController***. In the controller add the following action method.

   ```
   public ActionResult ReportViewer()
       {                
           ViewData["reportUrl"] = "../Reports/View/local/ClosingInventory/";

           return View();
       }
   ```
10. Add a view page click on the ***ReportViewer*** Controller. Name the view page ***ReportViewer.cshtml***. Add the following code to the view page.

    ```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login"))
     { 
           @Html.DropDownList("ddlYearMonthFormat", new SelectList(ViewBag.YearMonthFormat, "YearMonthValue",
     "YearMonthName"), new { @class = "DropDown" })

    Stock In Transit: @Html.TextBox("txtStockInTransit", "", new { @class = "LogInTextBox" })

    <input type="submit" onclick="return ReportValidationCheck();" name="ShowReport"
                     value="Show Report" />

    }
    ```
11. Add an ***Iframe***. Set the property of the Iframe as follows

    ```
    frameborder="0"  width="1000"; height="1000"; style="overflow:hidden;"
    scrolling="no"
    ```
12. Add Following JavaScript to the viewer.

    ```
    function ReportValidationCheck() {

        var url = $('#hdUrl').val();
        var yearmonth = $('#ddlYearMonthFormat').val();      
        var stockInTransit = $('#txtStockInTransit').val()

        if (stockInTransit == "") {
            stockInTransit = 0;
        }

        if (yearmonth == "0") {
            alert("Please Select Month Correctly.");
        }
        else {

            //url = url + "dpSpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpStockInTransit=" + stockInTransit;

            url = "../Reports/ReportView.aspx?rptmode=local&reportname=ClosingInventory&parameters=dpSpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpStockInTransit=" + stockInTransit;

            var myframe = document.getElementById("ifrmReportViewer");
            if (myframe !== null) {
                if (myframe.src) {
                    myframe.src = url;
                }
                else if (myframe.contentWindow !== null && myframe.contentWindow.location !== null) {
                    myframe.contentWindow.location = url;
                }
                else { myframe.setAttribute('src', url); }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    ```
13. ***Web.config*** file add the following key to the ***appSettings*** section

    ```
    add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"
    ```
14. In ***system.web*** ***handlers*** Section add the following key

    ```
    add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    ```
15. Change your data source to your own. This solution is very simple and I think every one will enjoy it.

Comment: Lol for simple task and 400 lines answer

Comment: And two mysterious variables declared from what library nobody knows, `RASolarERPData dal` and `List<ClosingInventoryValuation> objClosingInventory`.

Comment: Dal is Data Access Layer from which a method is called to fill data to the list.                                                   objClosingInventory = dal.ClosingInventoryReport(this.ReportDataObj.DataParameters[0].Value);

Answer (score 7):

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with SSRS 2008 and I couldn't get @Adrian's to work 100% for me when trying to get reports from a remote server.

Finally, I found that I needed to change the Page_Load method in **ViewUserControl1.ascx** to look like this:

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
ServerReport serverReport = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<Server Name>/reportserver");
serverReport.ReportPath = "/My Folder/MyReport";
serverReport.Refresh();
```

I had been missing the **ProcessingMode.Remote**.

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx - ReportViewer

Comment: Thank you a lot! I've been trying to make it work for couple of hours! You really saved my day! Thank you again!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the complete solution for directly integrating a report-viewer control (as well as any asp.net server side control) in an MVC .aspx view, which will also work on a report with multiple pages (unlike Adrian Toman's answer) and with AsyncRendering set to true, (based on "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework" by Steve Sanderson).

What one needs to do is basically:

1. Add a form with runat = "server"
2. Add the control, (for report-viewer controls it can also sometimes work even with AsyncRendering="True" but not always, so check in your specific case)
3. Add server side scripting by using script tags with runat = "server"
4. Override the Page_Init event with the code shown below, to enable the use of PostBack and Viewstate

Here is a demonstration:

```
<form ID="form1" runat="server">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" />
</form>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Handler = Page;
    }
    //Other code needed for the report viewer here        
</script>
```

It is of course recommended to fully utilize the MVC approach, by preparing all needed data in the controller, and then passing it to the view via the ViewModel.

This will allow reuse of the View!

However this is only said for data this is needed for every post back, or even if they are required only for initialization if it is not data intensive, and the data also has not to be dependent on the PostBack and ViewState values.

However even data intensive can sometimes be encapsulated into a lambda expression and then passed to the view to be called there.

A couple of notes though:

- By doing this the view essentially turns into a web form with all it's drawbacks, (i.e. Postbacks, and the possibility of non Asp.NET controls getting overriden)
- The hack of overriding Page_Init is undocumented, and it is subject to change at any time

Comment: I cant get this to work. The report still doesn't update on postback

Comment: @ministrymason try setting AsyncRendering to false, also I have only tested it on MVC 3, and of course note that it only works with an .aspx view and not a razor view

Comment: Same problem as @ministrymason. I'm calling it with `@Html.Partial` and it loads fine, but none of the controls work, such as page navigation, or expanding and collapsing table rows.

Comment: @Bjelovuk I have no access to your code, and even so I wouldn't say that troubleshooting would be easy, but I can give some suggestions, 1) Is the main view a razor view or aspx? 2) Does it work when it is not a partial? 3) Is the postback code emitted in the client side? What is happening behind the scenes on the HTTP level whe trying to navigate? 4) What is the base class of the view and what are the values of Handler and Page at render time?

Answer (score 6):

There's a MvcReportViewer helper in NuGet.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcReportViewer/

And this is the details:

https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer

I have using this. It works great.

Comment: Thanks for posting, this project is absolutely awesome. Just integrated into my application, quick and easy. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

the documentations refers to an ASP.NET application.
You can try and have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296485/bind-report-to-reportviewer-in-web-mvc2).
I have an example attached to my reply.
Another example for ASP.NET MVC3 can be found [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=669adf1af64df389&resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!155).

Answer (score 1):

You will not only have to use an asp.net page but

If using the Entity Framework or LinqToSql (if using partial classes) move the data into a separate project, the report designer cannot see the classes.

Move the reports to another project/dll, VS10 has bugs were asp.net projects cannot see object datasources in web apps.  Then stream the reports from the dll into your mvc projects aspx page.

This applies for mvc and webform projects.  Using sql reports in the local mode is not a pleasent development experience.  Also watch your webserver memory if exporting large reports.   The reportviewer/export is very poorly designed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get an SSRS report to appear on an MVC page without using iFrames or an aspx page.

The bulk of the work is explained here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx

The link explains how to create a web service and MVC action method that will allow you to call the reporting service and render result of the web service as an Excel file. With a small change to the code in the example you can render it as HTML.

All you need to do then is use a button to call a javascript function that makes an AJAX call to your MVC action which returns the HTML of the report. When the AJAX call returns with the HTML just replace a div with this HTML.

We use AngularJS so my example below is in that format, but it could be any javascript function

```
$scope.getReport = function()
{
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "Report/ExportReport",
        data: 
                [
                    { Name: 'DateFrom', Value: $scope.dateFrom },
                    { Name: 'DateTo', Value: $scope.dateTo },
                    { Name: 'LocationsCSV', Value: $scope.locationCSV }
                ]

    })
    .success(function (serverData)
    {
        $("#ReportDiv").html(serverData);
    });

};
```

And the Action Method - mainly taken from the above link...

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public FileContentResult ExportReport([FromBody]List<ReportParameterModel> parameters)
    {
         byte[] output;
         string extension, mimeType, encoding;
         string reportName = "/Reports/DummyReport";
         ReportService.Warning[] warnings;
         string[] ids;

     ReportExporter.Export(
            "ReportExecutionServiceSoap" 
            new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"),
            reportName,
            parameters.ToArray(),
            ExportFormat.HTML4,
            out output,
            out extension,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out warnings,
            out ids
        );

        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        // Set HTTP Response Header to show download dialog popup
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=GeneratedExcelFile{0:yyyyMMdd}.{1}", DateTime.Today, extension));
        return new FileContentResult(output, mimeType);
    }
```

So the result is that you get to pass parameters to an SSRS reporting server which returns a report which you render as HTML. Everything appears on the one page. This is the best solution I could find