# Mvc3 with viewreports.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

I'm trying to show reports with MVC3 and using razor.  I found links on internet where you only download the reports without showing a preview: [For example](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/11/25/rendering-an-rdlc-directly-to-the-response-stream-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx), but I would like to show a preview using the ReportViewer. Searching again i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/using-reportviewer-control-in-mvc) other example where a guy made a version for Mvc2 and VS2008 and it worked fine, but when i changed to Mvc3 i got a infinite loading bar showing the ReportViewer. [Here is the ReportViewer for Mvc3](http://www.mediafire.com/?4nr22fpzf7icdz0).

Here are some files:
**Report.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <a href="../../Reports/Report.aspx" target="_blank">Print this...</a>
</asp:Content>
```

**Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <a href="../../Reports/Report.aspx" target="_blank">Print this...</a>
</asp:Content>
```

Any help with Mvc3 ReportViewer.

Ps: Dont want use Telerik and others paying libraries.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

ReportViewer is a server control and can't be added into a razor view. You can added a ReportViewer into any ASPX view page or view user control.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513) for more details.