# MVC3 Razor VS2010 ReportViewer example

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reportviewer

Can anyone point me to a working example of showing a report in mvc3 ie the full code, I have looked at some examples and they look like they are going to do the job but then just blow up, I know that a ASPX page is needed and there seems to be a good example at [How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view)
when I created a clean app i get **Microsoft JScript** runtime error: 'Microsoft' is undefined I know it is probably something simple but its been a while since I used **Rdlc** files so somthing showing a simple report populated via an **xml datasource** would be great, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple task. You can follow the following steps.

1. Create a folder in your solution and give a name ***Reports***.
2. Add a ASP.Net web form and named it ***ReportView.aspx***
3. Create a Class ***ReportData*** and add it to the ***Reports*** folder. Add the  following code to the Class.

   ```
   public class ReportData
   {
       public ReportData()
       {
           this.ReportParameters = new List<Parameter>();
           this.DataParameters = new List<Parameter>();
       }

   public bool IsLocal { get; set; }
   public string ReportName { get; set; }
   public List<Parameter> ReportParameters { get; set; }
   public List<Parameter> DataParameters { get; set; }
   }

   public class Parameter
   {
   public string ParameterName { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Add another Class and named it ***ReportBasePage.cs***. Add the following code in this Class.

   ```
   public class ReportBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected ReportData ReportDataObj { get; set; }

       protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnInit(e);
           if (HttpContext.Current != null)
               if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportData"] != null)
               {
                   ReportDataObj = HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportData"] as ReportData;
                   return;
               }
           ReportDataObj = new ReportData();
           CaptureRouteData(Page.Request);
       }


       private void CaptureRouteData(HttpRequest request)
       {
           var mode = (request.QueryString["rptmode"] + "").Trim();
           ReportDataObj.IsLocal = mode == "local" ? true : false;
           ReportDataObj.ReportName = request.QueryString["reportname"] + "";
           string dquerystr = request.QueryString["parameters"] + "";
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dquerystr.Trim()))
           {
               var param1 = dquerystr.Split(',');
               foreach (string pm in param1)
               {
                   var rp = new Parameter();
                   var kd = pm.Split('=');
                   if (kd[0].Substring(0, 2) == "rp")
                   {
                       rp.ParameterName = kd[0].Replace("rp", "");
                       if (kd.Length > 1) rp.Value = kd[1];
                       ReportDataObj.ReportParameters.Add(rp);
                   }
                   else if (kd[0].Substring(0, 2) == "dp")
                   {
                       rp.ParameterName = kd[0].Replace("dp", "");
                       if (kd.Length > 1) rp.Value = kd[1];
                       ReportDataObj.DataParameters.Add(rp);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add ***ScriptManager*** to the ***ReportView.aspx*** page. Now Take a *Report Viewer* to the page. In report viewer set the property ***AsyncRendering="false"***. The code is given below.

   ```
       <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerRSFReports" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false"
           Width="1271px" Height="1000px" >
       </rsweb:ReportViewer>
   ```
6. Add two ***NameSpace*** in ***ReportView.aspx.cs***

   ```
   using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
   using System.IO;
   ```

Change the ***System.Web.UI.Page*** to ***ReportBasePage***. Just replace your code using the following.

```
public partial class ReportView : ReportBasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RenderReportModels(this.ReportDataObj);
            }
        }

        private void RenderReportModels(ReportData reportData)
        {
            RASolarERPData dal = new RASolarERPData();
            List<ClosingInventoryValuation> objClosingInventory = new List<ClosingInventoryValuation>();

            // Reset report properties.
            ReportViewerRSFReports.Height = Unit.Parse("100%");
            ReportViewerRSFReports.Width = Unit.Parse("100%");
            ReportViewerRSFReports.CssClass = "table";

            // Clear out any previous datasources.
            this.ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

            // Set report mode for local processing.
            ReportViewerRSFReports.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

            // Validate report source.
            var rptPath = Server.MapPath(@"./Report/" + reportData.ReportName +".rdlc");

            //@"E:\RSFERP_SourceCode\RASolarERP\RASolarERP\Reports\Report\" + reportData.ReportName + ".rdlc";
            //Server.MapPath(@"./Report/ClosingInventory.rdlc");

            if (!File.Exists(rptPath))
                return;

            // Set report path.
            this.ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.ReportPath = rptPath;

            // Set report parameters.
            var rpPms = ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.GetParameters();
            foreach (var rpm in rpPms)
            {
                var p = reportData.ReportParameters.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ParameterName.ToLower() == rpm.Name.ToLower());
                if (p != null)
                {
                    ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter(rpm.Name, p.Value);
                    ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp);
                }
            }

            //Set data paramater for report SP execution
            objClosingInventory = dal.ClosingInventoryReport(this.ReportDataObj.DataParameters[0].Value);

            // Load the dataSource.
            var dsmems = ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames();
            ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsmems[0], objClosingInventory));

            // Refresh the ReportViewer.
            ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

1. Add a Folder to the ***Reports*** Folder and named it ***Report***. Now add a ***RDLC*** report to the ***Reports/Report*** folder and named it ***ClosingInventory.rdlc***.
2. Now add a Controller and Named it ***ReportController***. In t
   o the controller add the following action method.

   ```
       public ActionResult ReportViewer()
       {                
           ViewData["reportUrl"] = "../Reports/View/local/ClosingInventory/";

           return View();
       }
   ```
3. Add a view page click on the ***ReportViewer*** Controller. Named the view page ***ReportViewer.cshtml***. Add the following code to the view page.

   ```
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Login"))
       { 
             @Html.DropDownList("ddlYearMonthFormat", new SelectList(ViewBag.YearMonthFormat, "YearMonthValue", "YearMonthName"), new { @class = "DropDown" })

    Stock In Transit: @Html.TextBox("txtStockInTransit", "", new { @class = "LogInTextBox" })

   <input type="submit" onclick="return ReportValidationCheck();" name="ShowReport"
                       value="Show Report" />

    }
   ```
4. Add an ***Iframe***. Set the property of the Iframe as follows

   ```
     frameborder="0"  width="1000"; height="1000"; style="overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no"
   ```
5. Add Following JavaScript to the viewer.

   ```
       function ReportValidationCheck() {

       var url = $('#hdUrl').val();
       var yearmonth = $('#ddlYearMonthFormat').val();      
       var stockInTransit = $('#txtStockInTransit').val()

       if (stockInTransit == "") {
           stockInTransit = 0;
       }

       if (yearmonth == "0") {
           alert("Please Select Month Correctly.");
       }
       else {

           //url = url + "dpSpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpStockInTransit=" + stockInTransit;

           url = "../Reports/ReportView.aspx?rptmode=local&reportname=ClosingInventory&parameters=dpSpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpYearMonth=" + yearmonth + ",rpStockInTransit=" + stockInTransit;

           var myframe = document.getElementById("ifrmReportViewer");
           if (myframe !== null) {
               if (myframe.src) {
                   myframe.src = url;
               }
               else if (myframe.contentWindow !== null && myframe.contentWindow.location !== null) {
                   myframe.contentWindow.location = url;
               }
               else { myframe.setAttribute('src', url); }
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```
6. ***Web.config*** file add the following key to the ***appSettings*** section

   ```
   add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"
   ```

In ***system.web*** ***handlers*** Section add the following key

```
add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

1. Change your data source as your own. This solution is very simple and I think every one enjoy it.