# Using ReportViewer server control with a parameterized server report in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, reportviewer, webforms

I am trying out using ReportViewer in an ASP.NET MVC project, and it worked well. However, when I introduced a parameter in the report, the ReportViewer failed to display the report. In other words, In ReportViewer you specify the parameter value and hit 'View Report', but nothing is displayed. I tried out retrieving the same report with same parameter value from an ASP.NET WebForms project with ReportViewer, and it worked perfectly fine.

**My report** is a server (rdl) report hosted in SQL Server 2008 R2.

**My MVC project** is the same as the [best answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view), except that I am using a server report with a parameter.

**The error** is a JavaScript error, here is the full exception stack:

> Uncaught exception:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Error thrown at line
>   869, column 12 in Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error,
>   executor, data) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=9h24dbJaaly3rGMpfScOygOpMl0i9ZEfurAVmwlb3Yl0rMGkCKy1xLKet_d0sBUJJ4e0MXKZS5XmIx-OivjpZk0ANckormmfPEBQ-Afm2nzOCuVDyyfYtP5j0AZgct8H67Sb-su3x9adK7hL6Sr6mSRruPOfgpwkAx7FkQnNwxll0rK_eH5XspKF7I4bOja30&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       throw error; called from line 1410, column 12 in Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_parseDelta(executor) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=9h24dbJaaly3rGMpfScOygOpMl0i9ZEfurAVmwlb3Yl0rMGkCKy1xLKet_d0sBUJJ4e0MXKZS5XmIx-OivjpZk0ANckormmfPEBQ-Afm2nzOCuVDyyfYtP5j0AZgct8H67Sb-su3x9adK7hL6Sr6mSRruPOfgpwkAx7FkQnNwxll0rK_eH5XspKF7I4bOja30&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       this._endPostBack(this._createPageRequestManagerParserError(String.format(Sys.WebForms.Res.PRM_ParserErrorDetails,
>   parserErrorDetails)), executor, ); called from line 1289, column 8 in
>   Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted(sender,
>   eventArgs) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=9h24dbJaaly3rGMpfScOygOpMl0i9ZEfurAVmwlb3Yl0rMGkCKy1xLKet_d0sBUJJ4e0MXKZS5XmIx-OivjpZk0ANckormmfPEBQ-Afm2nzOCuVDyyfYtP5j0AZgct8H67Sb-su3x9adK7hL6Sr6mSRruPOfgpwkAx7FkQnNwxll0rK_eH5XspKF7I4bOja30&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       var data = this._parseDelta(sender); called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 47, column 8 in () in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       return method.apply(instance, arguments); called from line 3484, column 16 in (source, args) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       evt[i](source, args); called from line 6364, column 12 in Sys$Net$WebRequest$completed(eventArgs) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       handler(this._executor, eventArgs); called from line 5984, column 16 in () in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       _this._webRequest.completed(Sys.EventArgs.Empty);
>
> Error created at line 237, column 4 in Error$create(message,
>   errorInfo) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       var err = new Error(message); called from line 649, column 8 in Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerParserError(parserErrorMessage)
>   in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=9h24dbJaaly3rGMpfScOygOpMl0i9ZEfurAVmwlb3Yl0rMGkCKy1xLKet_d0sBUJJ4e0MXKZS5XmIx-OivjpZk0ANckormmfPEBQ-Afm2nzOCuVDyyfYtP5j0AZgct8H67Sb-su3x9adK7hL6Sr6mSRruPOfgpwkAx7FkQnNwxll0rK_eH5XspKF7I4bOja30&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       var e = Error.create(displayMessage, {name: 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException'}); called from
>   line 1410, column 12 in
>   Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_parseDelta(executor) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=9h24dbJaaly3rGMpfScOygOpMl0i9ZEfurAVmwlb3Yl0rMGkCKy1xLKet_d0sBUJJ4e0MXKZS5XmIx-OivjpZk0ANckormmfPEBQ-Afm2nzOCuVDyyfYtP5j0AZgct8H67Sb-su3x9adK7hL6Sr6mSRruPOfgpwkAx7FkQnNwxll0rK_eH5XspKF7I4bOja30&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       this._endPostBack(this._createPageRequestManagerParserError(String.format(Sys.WebForms.Res.PRM_ParserErrorDetails,
>   parserErrorDetails)), executor, null); called from line 1289, column 8
>   in Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted(sender,
>   eventArgs) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=9h24dbJaaly3rGMpfScOygOpMl0i9ZEfurAVmwlb3Yl0rMGkCKy1xLKet_d0sBUJJ4e0MXKZS5XmIx-OivjpZk0ANckormmfPEBQ-Afm2nzOCuVDyyfYtP5j0AZgct8H67Sb-su3x9adK7hL6Sr6mSRruPOfgpwkAx7FkQnNwxll0rK_eH5XspKF7I4bOja30&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       var data = this._parseDelta(sender); called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 47, column 8 in () in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       return method.apply(instance, arguments); called from line 3484, column 16 in (source, args) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       evt[i](source, args); called from line 6364, column 12 in Sys$Net$WebRequest$completed(eventArgs) in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       handler(this._executor, eventArgs); called from line 5984, column 16 in () in
>   localhost:63763/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kl0znaGl8mJnEQzUd91vqZhniJAoaXveYJu32ah4gLsmHOPWa96ICxMfSrJe-fpz4tHJdIFn_hkaL1FO-AADXzl-rRWgsT1CLV7B_tLY183SFpWsMANof_Lmsl3J9tuuHqYkhyJ_KZWOgebGYCVK5wpsX3XToZdY9wOAYQkNoVcAAlWiP-4bSDdiID80dex0&t=ffffffff940d030f:
>       _this._webRequest.completed(Sys.EventArgs.Empty);

I believe something is missing in my settings. Again, my web.config is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view).

Comment: all the gibberish from this question led me to my answer.  See below.

Answer (score 3):

Reading that other question you linked, I am presuming the other difference is you have not included the following. Personally I have used a similar approach and couldn't get AsyncRendering working.

TLDR: Set AsyncRendering to false like:

```
AsyncRendering="false"
```

Comment: same here: AsyncRendering="false", damn...hours wasted google'ing