# Postback issue for reportviewer control in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

I need reportviewer control in my ASP.net MVC3 application. 
VS2010 
ReportViewer V10.0

I tried using following solution. I created user control and put reportviewer control there.

[How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view/7176529#7176529)

Code is same as shown in above link.

The problem is,
- if I hit next page or last page, it stays there only. 
- if I allow user to enter parameter and than click view report button on report viewer, it does nothing.

I know the reason, its losing its state. Its postback issue. If its regular aspx page i can control that in page_load by "!IsPostBack" but how to do that in user control. I tried putting IsPostback on control page_load but its always false.

My code is same as listed in above link. I am using user control.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick and make IsPostBack=true on post back:

```
<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Handler = this.Page;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please note it is for MVC. Postback, Page_init and similar web form concept not applies here.

Comment: The question was about using .ascx control in MVC application. It is possible to render .ascx control in MVC view via @Html.Partial("UserControlName"). But unfortunately, the IsPostBack is always false in the user control unless the above trick is applied. Page_Init is not valid in MVC, but it is valid in .ascx user controls.

Comment: @shapkin Thanks, it helped me out with a page containing a report viewer which was an infinite loop of postbacks.