# report viewer with razor engine

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor, reporting-services

Is it possible to insert a report viewer into a .cshtml file? I'm using Razor view Engine and I already have a report. I just want to insert that report into a view of mine. Thank you

Comment: Look this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view