# ReportViewer ASP.NET white lines

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, report, reportviewer

I was hoping someone could help me with this. I have added the ReportViewer Control to an ASP.NET MVC Page. The Problem is the White Lines that appear. They don't appear when you export the report, view it in the designer, or in a windows form Control. I was wondering if this was a setting/bug in the ReportViewer Control for ASP.NET MVC and if so is there a fix?

How I added the Control to ASP.NET MVC Page: [How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view)

How the Report Looks in the ReportViewer: http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa78/shelby1155/ReportViewer.png

How the Report is supposed to look: http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa78/shelby1155/Report.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem of the reportviewer control.
This appears to be CSS styling rule that you are applying on your page.

When your report is rendered in reportviewer control, it writes out the report in html.

The CSS rules that you have on your page seem to have a far reaching effect.

You could fix your CSS so that the reportviewer generated html is left out.

Or you could use the AsyncRendering feature, that puts the report in an iframe of its own.
Using AsyncRendering also has the advantage of allowing your page to complete rendering faster, as the report renders and loads independently in an embedded iframe.

```
AsyncRendering=True
```