# How to embed a rdl report on asp.net mvc razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view)

Is it possible? How can we implement?

If it is impossible to do that? Can anyone suggest some solution for reporting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently handled this requirement in an MVC project. You will have to add a webform (.aspx) page to your MVC project and then drop the reportviewer control like below(assuming you know how to work with reportviewer control) :

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

This is where ASP.net is coming together. In your project, you can use a webform page, SignalR,WebApI,etc. You can read more on One ASP.net post by Scott Hanselman. Here is a link:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Check Scott Hanselman's presentations as well

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETForMobileOneASPNETAndRealtimeASPNETWithSignalrVideoOfScottHanselmansTalksInRussia.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no control for ASP.Net MVC for Reports in rdl.

But you can do it through integration with asp.net webforms.
You can add special webforms page to your MVC project and add to it ReportViewer Control. Then, in codebehind, initiate this control and so on. ReportViewer Control is in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms assembly.