# SessionState server not working in WebForm inside MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I have a MVC4 app that is using a ReportViewer control on a aspx page inside a iframe in my razor view. I followed this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055132/876511.

Well this worked ok on localhost but it doesn't when i deploy to server.

First error i got was solved by setting the "Copy Local" property to true of the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms Reference.

Than I got this error on server: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common". For that i manually copied the dll from "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91" to the bin directory on server.

But now i'm getting this error that i can't figure it out:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +414
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +83    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo
>   sqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan retryInterval) +110
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session
>   database.]
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection
>   conn, Exception e) +235
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo
>   sqlPartitionInfo, TimeSpan retryInterval) +944
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id,
>   Boolean& usePooling) +231
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean
>   newItem) +199
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs) +798
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

What network path? The SQL Server? The rest of the app gets there fine.

Please help me, i have been stuck here for a few days and have no more ideias.

**EDIT:**

Found out where the error is. In my web.config.release i have this:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVER;User ID=ASPState;Password=XXXXXXX" timeout="120" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

When i comment out the reportViewer works, otherwise it gives network error. Somethings wrong, probably with the conn string, not sure what.

**EDIT2:**
Conn string is fine otherwise would not work on the intire app.

My new guess is because its a mix of MVC and Webforms... 
The mvc connects ok to the sessionstate server but my webform doesnt. Why?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ReportViewerRSFReports.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewerRSFReports.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials("user", "pass", "domain");
ReportViewerRSFReports.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<Server Name>/ReportServer");
ReportViewerRSFReports.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/MYAPP/test";
ReportViewerRSFReports.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Replace `reportserver.mydomain` with your ReportServer.

To a vaoid errors, i normally get the report server url and report path from BID out put windows during report deployment.

Comment: It doesn't work either. The error occurs before these lines. Its trying to connect to something before i set the reportserver. I tried not set at all the server and still get the same error on deply server and diferente error on localhost