# Why is my rdlc report not loading data in webform?

Tags: webforms

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32883635/6266949),  I tried to load data in my rdlc report. Data is coming from a view in the database. I used exactly the same code lines as in the link above.

The problem is that the report is displayed but with no data inside it. BUT in the debugger, the `List<>` supposed to fill the dataset is not empty. The variable `rdc` contains 12 items in my case.
What could cause this issue ?