# Dynamically set PageHeight in RDLC Report

Tags: model-view-controller, rdlc

I have an RDLC Report which retrieves around 10000 rows from the database. I am generating an image of the RDLC Report but the image is breaking in between and not showing all the records.
I have tried setting the Page height in Report Properties but it is not working.

How can I set the page height dynamically to incorporate all the rows in the image??

Comment: Hi, are you fixed the problem? and how?

Answer (score 0):

I made an RDLC Report with the help of report viewer (in an aspx page) and integrated that in my controller.

Refer this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view/7176529#7176529)