# Microsoft rdlc report in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, rdlc

I want to generate report in MVC4 application. I am trying by Microsoft RDLC report but i don't 
want to create a data-set. i am creating my own list of data and that list i want to show in the report.
 I am creating list after fetching data from various table.
I had gone through various links but all links given me the steps to create report with data-set.

I tried to get some from [Google](http://google.com), but do not found any reliable solution for same..
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view/7176529#7176529), and [google](https://www.google.co.uk/#safe=on&q=how+to+use+rdlc+report+in+mvc+4) in this case might be helpful too. As for how to use your custom objects, refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252094.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We are using

```
public ReportDataSourceCollection DataSources { get; }
```

from Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
and then add a custom datasource to our report engine with

```
myReportEngine.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyData", data));
```

where data can be DataTable, IDataSource or an IEnumerable as you need it.

In the report definition (rdlc) we use the following dummy data set that maps to our data

```
<DataSources>
  <DataSource Name="MyDataSource">
    <ConnectionProperties>
      <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
      <ConnectString>data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyDataCollection</ConnectString>
      <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
    </ConnectionProperties>
  </DataSource>
</DataSources>
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="MyData">
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="MyField1">
        <DataField>MyField1</DataField>
    </Field>
    ...
   </Fields>
  </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

Comment: MyDataCollection and MyDataSource must not be set in code.

Comment: i did ny this way only but event though we have to set dataset to rdlc report.