# ReportViewer component not rendering on IIS 8

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, reportviewer

I've implemented `ReportViewer` component in my **MVC 5** application as it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055132/4703971).

On my local machine it works like a charm. But after deploying I only see a blank page. I'm sure it's not a problem with handler, because there're 4 requests to `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd` which return splitters, spinningwheel and viewerscript. Also there're 3 requests to `ScriptResource.axd` and 1 to `WebResource.axd`.

It finishes with post-request, which returns `'Ok'`. The behaviour's just like on my local machine, absolutely no errors. I tried everything about adding/migrating records in `Web.Config`, switching between classic/integrated modes, sharing permissions, copying assemblies, etc.

No result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forget to set chechbox **always copy** in `.rdlc` files properties.

So you just don't have your reports on server.

Comment: oh man, you just came and did it! Saved me from falling deeply insane and maybe loosing job, family, friends... Who knows, what'd be the next without your help? I... I mean... I just want to say how great your advice is and GOD BLESS YOUR HOUSE (i'm not a christian, so i surely mean NyanGod)