# How can I use RDLC ( Microsoft Reports ) in MVC5 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, rdlc

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 and a MVC5 project with Entity Framework 6.

I have created my MVC5 project so I need to create reports with RDLC (Microsoft Reports) ,i know it is faster than crystal report and i think easier than crystal also so i want to know how i can use RDLC and what is the steps to create it because for me it is first time to create reports .

Any idea or suggestion or tutorial how can I do that?

thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-tutorials-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check my answer on this thread, which clearly shows how to render your rdlc report:

- [RDLC report MVC 5 without iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613151/rdlc-report-mvc-5-without-iframe/58269516#58269516)

See [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implementing-RDLC-Reports-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) on the primary steps to integrate your rdlc report with entity-framework and MVC 5.